# Force Feedback Joystick support (MS Sidewinder FF2)

Tags: joystick

I want to figure out how much my force feedback joystick is actually supported in Ubuntu. Currently I have Ubuntu 20.04.05 LTS installed.

So far I can run

```
$ lsusb 
...
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:001b Microsoft Corp. SideWinder Force Feedback 2 Joystick
...
$
```

and

```
$ jstest /dev/input/js0
Driver version is 2.1.0.
Joystick (Microsoft SideWinder Force Feedback 2 Joystick) has 6 axes (X, Y, Rz, Throttle, Hat0X, Hat0Y)
and 9 buttons (Trigger, ThumbBtn, ThumbBtn2, TopBtn, TopBtn2, PinkieBtn, BaseBtn, BaseBtn2, BtnDead).
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Axes:  0:  1852  1:     0  2:     0  3:     0  4:     0  5:     0 Buttons:  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  7:off  8:on
```

Both of them seem working fine, so the basic joystick functionality is good.
Next, I want to check force feedback functionality. I read https://docs.kernel.org/input/ff.html
and thus tried

```
$ fftest /dev/input/js0
Force feedback test program.
HOLD FIRMLY YOUR WHEEL OR JOYSTICK TO PREVENT DAMAGES

Device /dev/input/js0 opened
Features:
Ioctl absolute axes features query: Invalid argument
```

but then the documentation talks about some eventXX device file. Unfortunately it does not mention which one to use. So I added my user to the `input` group and tried

```
$ fftest /dev/input/event0
Force feedback test program.
HOLD FIRMLY YOUR WHEEL OR JOYSTICK TO PREVENT DAMAGES

Device /dev/input/event0 opened
Features:
  * Absolute axes: 
    [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
  * Relative axes: 
    [00 00 ]
  * Force feedback effects types: 
    Force feedback periodic effects: 
    [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
  * Number of simultaneous effects: 0

Uploading effect #0 (Periodic sinusoidal) ... Error:: Function not implemented
Uploading effect #1 (Constant) ... Error: Function not implemented
Uploading effect #2 (Spring) ... Error: Function not implemented
Uploading effect #3 (Damper) ... Error: Function not implemented
Uploading effect #4 (Strong rumble, with heavy motor) ... Error: Function not implemented
Uploading effect #5 (Weak rumble, with light motor) ... Error: Function not implemented
Enter effect number, -1 to exit
```

Regardless of what number I enter, my joystick behaves the same: it uses force to just center the stick. Probably just because the functions are not implemented. But then the same happens, regardless of which file I specify:

```
/dev/input/event0
/dev/input/event1
/dev/input/event...
```

Is it the case that my joystick is not supported? According to https://docs.kernel.org/input/joydev/joystick.html#microsoft-sidewinder-joysticks the Overdrive Protocol seems there.

What else could be missing?

Comment: Please edit your question and add which distro and version of Linux you are using?

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled across another command from the force feedback/joystick suite:
evtest

Running this as root revealed a huge list of 23 devices but also mentioned their name:

```
# evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
...
/dev/input/event23: Microsoft SideWinder Force Feedback 2 Joystick
Select the device event number [0-23]:
```

With that hint, I ran fftest again and got this output:

```
# fftest /dev/input/event23
Force feedback test program.
HOLD FIRMLY YOUR WHEEL OR JOYSTICK TO PREVENT DAMAGES

Device /dev/input/event23 opened
Features:
  * Absolute axes: X, Y, RZ, Throttle, Hat 0 X, Hat 0 Y, 
    [63 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 ]
  * Relative axes: 
    [00 00 ]
  * Force feedback effects types: Constant, Periodic, Ramp, Spring, Friction, Damper, Rumble, Inertia, Gain, Autocenter, 
    Force feedback periodic effects: Square, Triangle, Sine, Saw up, Saw down, 
    [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 1F 03 00 00 00 ]
  * Number of simultaneous effects: 40

Setting master gain to 75% ... OK
Uploading effect #0 (Periodic sinusoidal) ... OK (id 0)
Uploading effect #1 (Constant) ... OK (id 1)
Uploading effect #2 (Spring) ... OK (id 2)
Uploading effect #3 (Damper) ... OK (id 3)
Uploading effect #4 (Strong rumble, with heavy motor) ... OK (id 4)
Uploading effect #5 (Weak rumble, with light motor) ... OK (id 5)
Enter effect number, -1 to exit
```

So it seems the Force Feedback 2 joystick is detected by the kernel, and it is known to support five different effects. Entering some effect number like `4` really makes the stick shake for a few seconds.

There is yet another nice command to play with:

```
ffcfstress -d /dev/input/event23
```

Check out https://github.com/flosse/linuxconsole:

```
Joystick utilities
------------------

The following utilities are provided to calibrate and test joysticks:
* ffcfstress, ffmvforce, fftest - test force-feedback devices
* ffset - set force-feedback device parameters
* jscal - calibrate joystick devices, reconfigure the axes and buttons
* jscal-store, jscal-restore - store and retrieve joystick device
  settings as configured using jscal
* jstest - test joystick devices
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have come across the real issue. The kernel documentation https://docs.kernel.org/input/joydev/joystick.html#microsoft-sidewinder-joysticks lists these supported devices:

- Microsoft SideWinder 3D Pro
- Microsoft SideWinder Force Feedback Pro
- Microsoft SideWinder Force Feedback Wheel
- Microsoft SideWinder FreeStyle Pro
- Microsoft SideWinder GamePad (up to four, chained)
- Microsoft SideWinder Precision Pro
- Microsoft SideWinder Precision Pro USB

Notice something? The Force Feedback 2 joystick is not listed.
So I downloaded the kernel source code from https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/linux-6.1.6.tar.xz and checked the file `linux-6.1.6/drivers/input/joystick/sidewinder.c`. It contains

```
static char *sw_name[] = {  "3D Pro", "GamePad", "Precision Pro", "Force Feedback Pro", "FreeStyle Pro",
                "Force Feedback Wheel" };
```

which matches the above list but again omits the Force Feedback 2 joystick. Seems to be a forgotten artifact.